# Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://*.com/') with script ('https://*.com/service-worker.js'): Failed to access storage

Tags: service-worker

Why might the error happen: "Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://*.com/') with script ('https://*.com/service-worker.js'): Failed to access storage."?

service-worker.js code:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function() {
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});
```